# I want to create a user with sequelize and nodeJs but it didnt work

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I want to create a user but i dosen't work, when i tried it in postman , it send me an error and it dosen't work [this is postman response][1]
And after that it send me an error in terminal that user is not a constructor where it is a constructor
Why it didin't work ? where is the problem ?
Help me please
Help me please
Help me please
Help me please

this is my app.js

```
    const router = require('express').Router();
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const JWT =  require('jsonwebtoken');
let User = require('../models/user');
const saltRounds = 2;
  router.route('/createUser').post((req, res) => {
          bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, saltRounds, function(err, hash) {
            const newUser = new User({
              email : req.body.email,
              password : hash,
              username :  req.body.username,
              role:  req.body.role,
            });
            newUser.save()
            .then(user => { 
                const id = user._id;
                const token = JWT.sign({id}, process.env.JWTSECRET, {});
                const r = {isLogin : true, idUser : user._id, username : user.username, role: user.role, token: token };
                res.json(r);
                }
            )
            .catch(err => res.status(400).send((err).toString()));
          });
  });
router.route('/login').post((req, res) => {
    const user = req.body.email;
    const pass = req.body.password;
    Users.findOne({ email: user })
    .then(user => {
        if (user) {
            bcrypt.compare(pass, user.password, (error, response) => {
              if (response) {
                const id = user._id;
                const token = JWT.sign({id}, process.env.JWTSECRET, {});
                const r = {isLogin : true, idUser : user._id, username : user.username, level: user.role, token: token };
                res.json(r);
              }
              else {
                res.json({isLogin : false, message: "Email ou Mot de passe incorrecte !"})
              }
            });
        }
        else {
            res.json({isLogin : false, message: "Email ou Mot de passe incorrecte !"})
        }
    })
    .catch(err => res.status(400).send((err).toString()));
    
  });

module.exports = router;


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3c67R.png
```

Comment: are you exporting user model from `../models/user`?

Comment: yes I do of course

Answer (score 0):

Can you try once with this code?

```
router.route('/createUser').post(async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const hash = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, saltRounds);
        const newUser = new User({
            email: req.body.email,
            password: hash,
            username: req.body.username,
            role: req.body.role,
        });
        const user = await newUser.save();

        const id = user._id;
        const token = JWT.sign({id}, process.env.JWTSECRET, {});
        const r = {isLogin : true, idUser : user._id, username : user.username, role: user.role, token: token };
        return res.json(r);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(400).send((err).toString())
    }
});
```